# Change Date format during SQL

Tags: sql, select, format

I am moving data to a new database and need to so some formatting during the move to try and save me time.

The current DB saves the date as YYYYMMDD and the new DB wants it in mm/dd/yyyy. Can I do this during the move or will I have to format after?

Thank you all!

Comment: Which database is it?

Comment: From a SQL 2005 to a SQL 2014 sever

Answer (score 0):

You cold use the [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/hh213505.aspx) function . So I am not sure how you are getting the data to sql 2014 but once the data is there you could use this command.

This is an example selecting from a table that has a date and altering its format .

```
use AdventureWorks2012
go

select modifieddate as 'original format', FORMAT ( modifieddate, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'New format mm/dd/yy'
from [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
```

Query Result

[image]

If your data is not format and its just a string you could use the format command to add the separators .

This code create a table with a date as an INT, the selects the data and formats it as a data time into another table .

```
CREATE TABLE Test_TimeString (Timeint int)
    GO
    INSERT INTO  Test_TimeString VALUES(04242016)
    GO

    CREATE TABLE Test_Time (Timedate DATETIME)
    GO

    INSERT INTO Test_Time
    SELECT FORMAT(Timeint,'##/##/####')
    FROM  Test_TimeString

    SELECT * FROM Test_Time
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, the issue I am finding is that with no separation the the original date, format date doesn't work. Is there a way to select the first 4 numbers and then add 2 / after the move?

Comment: This would work for you ? IF you have any more questions please provide how your current table looks and what data types it has . For example I know are looking at a column with data and you want to turn that in to a data in a specific format, is this column a data time column , a varchaar or int ?

Comment: The current table has the date as YYYYMMDD

Example being 
20160401
20160402
20160403

If you dump the data to excel I can run the function 

=MID(A1,5,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,4) against the cell and it formats how I want it too. Is there something I can do during the query to do the same?